# Duplicate Encoder (duplicate letters in a string)

Tags: javascript

The goal is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is '(' if that character appears only once in the original string, or ')' if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

my problem is if it's repeating a letter first parenthese is showing wrong.

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){

  var repeat = [];
  var result = [];
  var letters = word.split('');
  for (i=0; i < letters.length; i++){
      if (repeat.indexOf(letters[i]) > -1) {
          result.push(")");
      } else {
          result.push("(");
      }
      repeat.push(letters[i]);
   }
   return result.join("");
 }
console.log(duplicateEncode("aleluia"))
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show explicitly what the desired output is for that input?

Comment: Is the desired outpu from `aleluia` -> `))()(()`?

Comment: that is because for the first iteration `repeat` array is empty.

Answer (score 3):

> *"my problem is if it's repeating a letter first parenthesis is showing wrong."*

This is because your code doesn't do any look-ahead, it only checks what characters have already been processed. One way or another you need to check if the current letter also appears earlier *or* later in the string.

The first way that came to mind was to start by counting all of the letters (putting the counts in an object), then map each letter based on its count. That way you only loop through the original word exactly twice:

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
  var letterCount = {};
  var letters = word.toLowerCase().split('');

  letters.forEach(function(letter) {
    letterCount[letter] = (letterCount[letter] || 0) + 1;
  });

  return letters.map(function(letter) {
    return letterCount[letter] === 1 ? '(' : ')';
  }).join('');
}

console.log(duplicateEncode("aleluia"))
console.log(duplicateEncode("AleLuia"))    
console.log(duplicateEncode("No duplicates"))
console.log(duplicateEncode("All duplicated ALL DUPLICATED"))
```

Or the same thing with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is only three lines:

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
  const letters = word.toLowerCase().split('');
  const counts = letters.reduce((ct, ltr) => ((ct[ltr] = (ct[ltr] || 0) + 1), ct), {});
  return letters.map(letter => counts[letter] === 1 ? '(' : ')').join('');
}

console.log(duplicateEncode("aleluia"))
console.log(duplicateEncode("AleLuia"))    
console.log(duplicateEncode("No duplicates"))
console.log(duplicateEncode("All duplicated ALL DUPLICATED"))
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your `forEach` does? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: @NewshaNik - I thought I did explain. It's looping over the `letters` array, and counting how many times each letter appears by using a count stored in the`letterCount` object. If you're not sure how JS objects work maybe find an online tutorial about that, I think explaining objects is beyond the scope of this question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
const duplicateEncode = word => {
    let newString = ''
    word = word.toLowerCase() || word
    word.split('').filter((x, index) => {
      if(word.indexOf(x) !== index){
        newString += ')'
      }else if(word.lastIndexOf(x) !== index){
        newString += ')'
      }else{
        newString += '('
      }
    })
    return newString
}
duplicateEncode("O!!!!@k!!!H!!!)!!n!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `.length` of each matched letter in string using `RegExp` constructor and `String.prototype.match()`. If `.length` of matched character is `1` return `"("` else return `")"`

```js
const word = "aleluia";
let res = [...word].map(letter =>
            word.match(new RegExp(letter, "ig")).length === 1 ? "(" : ")"
          ).join("");
          
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more simple way to solve this task. Guess it may be more understandable for newbies in JS because the following solution contains only 4 basic level methods. So here we go.

```
    function duplicateEncode(word) {
  return word
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .map(function (a, i, w) {
      return w.indexOf(a) == w.lastIndexOf(a) ? "(" : ")";
    })
    .join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so:

```
'a' => '('
'aa' => '))'
'aba' => ')()'
'abA' => ')()'

'aba'
  .toLowerCase()
  .split('')
  .reduce((acc, char, i, arr) => {
    const symbol = arr.filter(letter => letter === char).length < 2 ? '(' : ')'
    return acc + symbol
  }, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your `result` array is empty until the second iteration (i = 1). The solution is to start with an array with the first element.

```js
function duplicateEncode(word) {

  var repeat = [];
  var result = [];
  var letters = word.split('');
  for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    repeat.push(letters[0]);
    if (repeat.indexOf(letters[i]) > -1) {
      result.push(")");
    } else {
      result.push("(");
    }
    repeat.push(letters[i]);
  }
  return result.join("");
}
console.log(duplicateEncode("aleluia"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function duplicateEncode(word){
    let w = word.toLowerCase();
    return Array.from(w).map(x => w.replace( new RegExp(`[^${x}]`, 'g') , "").length > 1 ? ')' : '(').join('');
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.